# Limit of the Cardinality of Integer Sets

Tags: limits

Let the set $Z_n$ contain all the positive integers less than or equal to n. Let the set $E_n$ contain all the positive even integers less than or equal to n. $|S|$ is the cardinality of a set S. What would the following limit evaluate to?
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{|Z_n|}{|E_n|}$$
If the limit is evaluating the quotient for each $n$ as $n$ grows without bound, then the answer should be $2$. However the cardinality of the sets when $n$ is actually infinity is the same, making the limit equal to $1$. Is there a correct answer? I'm leaning towards $2$.

Comment: That limit is $2$ and $|\mathbb Z|=2|\mathbb N|$. I don't see a problem there. It should just tell you that you can't divide cardinals since $|\mathbb Z|=k\cdot |\mathbb N|$ for any $1\leq k\leq |\mathbb Z|$, meaning that division isn't well defined.

Comment: @MiloBrandt: Your comment is wrong. See *angryavian*'s answer.

Comment: @user21820 I don't see how angryavian's answer contradicts anything I wrote. We agree that the limit is $2$. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @MiloBrandt: You say that it tells you that you cannot divide cardinals. The point is that it is the limit of a ratio and not a ratio of the limit, so it has nothing to do with trying to divide |N| by |Z|. His answer is absolutely clear on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not actually defined $Z_\infty$ and $E_\infty$, and even if they were defined to be $\mathbb{N}$, you are not concerned with them because you are taking a limit as $n \to \infty$, **not** computing $Z_\infty/E_\infty$. Your justification for $2$ is correct.

Answer (score 2):

We have $\left\vert{Z_n}\right\vert = n$ and $\left\vert{E_n}\right\vert = \left \lfloor \frac {n} 2 \right \rfloor$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Thus
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\left\vert{Z_n}\right\vert}{\left\vert{E_n}\right\vert} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{\left \lfloor \frac {n} 2 \right \rfloor}= 2
$$

This is just a limit of real numbers and has little to do with cardinalities.

Comment: $|E_n|=\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$

Comment: @angryavian Thanks.

Comment: $\lfloor n \rfloor/2 \ne \lfloor n/2 \rfloor$

Comment: @angryavian Thanks again - I should probably get some sleep ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x) \not=f(a)$: The "limit" is 2, but "$f(a)$" is 1.

It's called discontinuity. It means there's no reason to expect that the two expressions have the same value.

Comment: I think $f(a)=1$ needs some justification.  The "obvious" $f(a)$, the ratio of cardinalities, would be $\aleph_0/\aleph_0$, which isn't defined.

Comment: Okay, that detail's wrong, but the idea is still correct.